# AppArmor: What does a single "files," clause without any additional parameters mean?

Tags: apparmor

Docker's [default container AppArmor profile](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/profiles/apparmor/template.go#L18) contains a single "file" clause, without any additional information:

```
file,
```

What does this really mean, does this clause grant full access to any file? I've checked with AppArmor's [apparmor.d(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/apparmor.d.5.html) man page, but it does not mention this case explicitly, contrary to, say:

```
# Allow all PTrace access
ptrace,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Months later I finally stumbled upon an explanation, not from the AppArmor project itself, but from OpenSUSE, in their "Security and Hardening Guide", chapter "Profile Components and Syntax", heading "[30.7.70 Optional allow and file Rules](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/security/html/book-security/cha-apparmor-profiles.html#sec-apparmor-profiles-perm-file-allow)":

> The following rule grants access to all files:
>
> ```
> file,
> ```